# Passing the Google cloud service account file to traefik

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, traefik

As per https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/acme/

I've created a secret like so:

`kubectl --namespace=gitlab-managed-apps create secret generic traefik-credentials \
--from-literal=GCE_PROJECT=<id> \
--from-file=GCE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE=key.json \`

And passed it to the helm chart by using: `--set acme.dnsProvider.$name=traefik-credentials`

However I am still getting the following error:

```
{"level":"error","msg":"Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"traefik.my.domain.com\" detected thanks to rule \"Host:traefik.my.domain.com\" : cannot get ACME client googlecloud: Service Account file missing","time":"2019-01-14T21:44:17Z"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why/if traefik uses `GCE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE` variable. All Google tooling and 3rd party integrations use `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable for that purpose (and all Google API clients automatically pick up this variable). So looks like traefik might have done a poor decision here calling it something else.

I recommend you look at the Pod spec of the traefik pod (fields `volumes` and `volumeMounts` to see if the Secret is mounted to the pod correctly).

If you follow this tutorial https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform you can learn how to mount IAM Service accounts to any Pod. So maybe you can combine this with the Helm chart itself and figure out what you need to do to make this work.

Comment: it's not Traefik's choice but [lego](https://github.com/xenolf/lego). Lego uses the [official API client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client), it supports `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` and Traefik also supports it.

Comment: Seems like there's no way of making this work with Traefik without modifying the actual template for the helm charts... I think this is really poorly documented on their part. :(